# Get a range of data which R^2 = 1 in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing a data reduction project for excel and I need to draw a pivot table using given data. But the R^2 value of the graph should be 1. I need to select the range which this requirement completes using macro.This is an image when the correct data range has not been selected

[image: Incorrect graph]

Range should be selected to show the table something like this.

[image: Correct graph]

These data has taken from a machine which send out some fault data in the first few seconds and last few seconds when it runs. otherwise it sends out data which fits perfectly for a y=mx+c graph. What I needs to do is select the range for a graph neglecting those false data.Is this possible to do using macro?

Comment: A *pivot table* is not the sort of thing which is drawn. Presumably you meant "chart". Your question itself isn't clear. Once you clarify it, the answer is undoubtedly "yes". It is possible to write macros to analyze data. Start writing such a macro and ask a focused question about it if and when you get stuck. As it is, the question is too broad.

Comment: You want to back your way into a set of data whose r-squared (assuming linear regression model) is 1? This seems fishy, but it's doable since I assume you know your y-intercept (`b`) and your slope `(m)` before hand, so the rest is just filling out `y` and `x` values in your linear regression of `y=mx+b`. In other words, determine the slope and y-intercept of your desired linear regression and then only select values that satisfy the equation when plugged into `y` and `x`.

Comment: Let me clarify this. These data has taken from a machine which send out some fault data in the first few seconds and last few seconds when it runs. ohterwise it sends out data which fits perfectly for a y=mx+c graph. What I needs to do is slsect the range for a graph neglecting those false data.

Comment: If the time between observations is constant, what you are trying to do is find the longest arithmetical subsequence of y values.

Comment: If you are confident that the data in the middle perfectly follows a line, you could find what that line is (the two middle points and basic algebra suffice) and throw away the data which doesn't lie on the line.

Answer (score 1):

**1.Determine your slope.**

Slope can be determined with the formula

```
 slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

So you only need to determine two GOOD points here, just plug your cells in for those `y2`, `y1`, `x1` and `x2` values and your are golden

**2.Determine your y-intercept**

Since you have a slope and a couple of good points to work with, you can now back your way into the y-intercept

```
 y1=slope_you_calculated*x1 + yintercept
```

or

```
 yintercept = y1 - (slope_you_calculated*x1)
```

Again just plug your cells into those `y1`, `slope_you_calculated` and `x1` positions and hit enter.

**3.Now you have all the pieces to test each row to see if it fits your formula. Assuming y values in column `A` and x values in column `B`:**

```
=if((slope_you_calculated*B1)+y_intercept_you_calculated = A1, "Match", "No Match")
```

Copy that down for all of your rows.

Anything with a `match` is going to give you an r-squared of 1 when graphed and trended with linear regression assuming you started by picking two good points.